# "require is not defined" - Does that mean I need RequireJs?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, webpack, karma-runner

I am trying to get karma running my tests.  My stack is:

- Webpack
- Karma
- Typescript
- Mocha

When I run my tests, I get the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

This is thrown from `core-js` (which I added to my karma config file to fix another error).

As I understand it, I should not need `RequireJs` if I am using webpack...

**Is there something I am missing?  Why is `require` not found?**

In case it is relevant, here are links to my config files: [karma.conf.js](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/bfd47c88853954b8cda2daf6193ac315#file-karma-config-js), [webpack.config.js](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/bfd47c88853954b8cda2daf6193ac315#file-webpack-config-js), [package.json](https://gist.github.com/Vaccano/bfd47c88853954b8cda2daf6193ac315#file-package-json)

Comment: How are you running your tests?

Comment: `npm run test`  (It runs `karma start`)

Answer (score 0):

I think I got this one figure out.

If you just add a file to karma, it does not get the loader benefits of webpack.

So all the `require` calls that are all over core-js are not able to work.

I moved to call to `core-js` inside my unit test file and it worked...